# protected internal class working within class but not working outside

Tags: c#, oop, internal, protected

I was trying few things and would like to know why this is happening so.

Say, I have a class called A in namespace n and I was trying to create protected internal class B.

```
namespace n
{
   public class A
   {
      public A()
      {
      }
   }
   protected internal class B //throwing error
   {
   }
}
```

But when i try like this (B as a sub class of A), its not throwing error and its built success. Could you explain me why it is so?

```
namespace n
{
   public class A
   {
      public A()
      {
      }
      protected internal class B // its not throwing error
      {
      }
   }      
}
```

Am i missing anything theoretically? Its quite a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the error.

> Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as
>   private, **protected**, or protected internal

Only internal or public members are allowed outside the class.

Your second case is defining the class B as member of class A that is why you are not getting the error.

You may see [Access Modifiers C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

> Classes and structs that are declared directly **within a namespace (in
>   other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs**) can
>   be either public or internal. Internal is the default if no access
>   modifier is specified.

Comment: Sealed can also be used as a class modifier for a class besides internal (default modifier) and public.

Answer (score 4):

A class can't be `protected` except when it is inside another class.

The `protected` keyword is only valid for *members of a class*. In your second example, `class B` happens to be that member.

Think about it:
`protected` means: Derived classes can access this member.
As there is no such concept as derived namespaces, the `protected` keyword doesn't make sense for members of a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

**protected** declares visiblity level for **derived** types.

In your first case you declare class inside `namespace`. There is no any polymophic support for namespaces, so there is no any sence of using protected classes in `namespace`

In second case, instead, you use it inside other classe (class `A`), which make it visible for all children of `A` class.