# Defined Elements cannot be explicitly declared as private or protected

Tags: c#, class, oop, access-modifiers

According to object oriented principles, we can define any class in any namespace as `private` or `protected` but when I create a class as `private` or `protected` I get the following compilation error:

> `Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, or protected internal`

```
namespace test
{
    public class A
    {
        public A()
        {
        }
    }

    protected  class B //throwing error
    {
    }
}
```

I searched for a solution and [I found the following on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403647/protected-internal-class-working-within-class-but-not-working-outside):

> Anything that is not a member of an enclosing type (class) doesn't make sense at all to be protected.

Why can't I declare `B` as `protected`?

I guess I don't understand what `protected` means. What does it mean?

Comment: Only nested classes can be marked as protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# you cannot declare classes as protected, except when they are nested within other classes:

```
namespace test
{
    public class A
    {
        public A()
        {
        }

        protected  class B // nested class
        {
        }
    } 
}
```

This makes sense because `protected` means that it should only be accessible by the **enclosing class** or a class derived from that enclosing class.

If it is ok if class B can be accessed by all classes in the same assembly but not from outside, you can declare the class as `internal`:

```
namespace test
{
    public class A
    {
        public A()
        {
        } 
    } 

    internal class B // accessible within same assembly
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only nested classes can be marked as `protected`.

```
namespace test
{
    public class A
    {
        public A() { }

        protected class B
        {
            public B() { }
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Protected says that the class can only be used inside the class it is specified in or inherited from. Therefore it does not make sense to declare a protected class in a namespace. What would this mean? Protected can only be applied to nested classes therefore.